# Mid function in Java - Similar to VB?

Tags: java, vb.net

In Visual Basic I used to use the Mid function to loop through a string and examine each character, i.e. like this:

```vb
For intPosition = 1 To strlength
    ' loop to examine each character in turn
    strchar = Mid(strstring, intposition, 1)
Next
```

Question is, how would I go about doing something similar using Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [charAt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) method of the String class.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`charAt(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) in java.

It returns,

> the char value at the specified index of this string. The first char
>   value is at index 0.

Answer (score 3):

For one character, `charAt`, or more generally the nearest equivalent to `Mid` is `substring`, though note that you provide the end position, not the character count. See:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int, int)

Answer (score 0):

I converted from an application I found in javascript to java.

```
    public String mid(String str, int start, int len){
    // Make sure start and len are within proper bounds
    if (start < 0 || len < 0) {
        return "";
    }

    int iEnd = 0;
    int iLen = str.length();

    if (start + len > iLen)
        iEnd = iLen;
    else
        iEnd = start + len;

    return str.substring(start,iEnd);
}
```